# Flutter/Firestore : Having troubles with read/write permissions

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make it so that my app only shows users 'tasks' that only that user has created. I have an account creation system and I dont want other accounts to be able to view and edit tasks that have been created by others. I have set up rules and changed my stream but it is giving me a permission denied error when creating tasks and viewing tasks. Am I doing something wrong here?

This is the error I'm getting..

> W/Firestore( 7671): (24.2.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(users/myemail@gmail.com order by **name**);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

This is my tasks code.. note the top of my _TasksState class where I declare the permissions

```js
class Tasks extends StatefulWidget {
  const Tasks({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Tasks> createState() => _TasksState();
}

String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

class _TasksState extends State<Tasks> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _stream =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('tasks').where("userId", isEqualTo: uid).snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[50],
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 20),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: const [
                    Text(
                        'Tasks',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 30,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                StreamBuilder(
                    stream: _stream,
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return const Text(
                          'There are no saved Tasks, click "Add Task" to get started!',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        );
                      }
                      return ListView.builder(
                        physics: const ScrollPhysics(parent: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()),
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            IconData iconDataValue;
                            Color iconColorValue;
                            Map<String, dynamic> data =
                                snapshot.data.docs[index].data()
                                    as Map<String, dynamic>;
                                    switch(data['category']) {
                                      case 'Order' : 
                                      iconDataValue = Icons.monetization_on;
                                      iconColorValue = Colors.white;
                                      break;
                                      case 'Build' : 
                                      iconDataValue = Icons.handyman;
                                      iconColorValue = Colors.white;
                                      break;
                                      case 'Pickup' : 
                                      iconDataValue = Icons.arrow_circle_up;
                                      iconColorValue = Colors.white;
                                      break;
                                      case 'Cleanup' : 
                                      iconDataValue = Icons.cleaning_services;
                                      iconColorValue = Colors.white;
                                      break;
                                      case 'Repair' : 
                                      iconDataValue = Icons.build;
                                      iconColorValue = Colors.white;
                                      break;
                                      default:
                                      iconDataValue = Icons.question_mark;
                                      iconColorValue = Colors.white;
                                    }
                            return InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ViewTaskData(data: data, id:snapshot.data.docs[index].id)));
                              },
                              child: TaskCard(
                                title: data['title'] == '' ? 'No Title' : data['title'],
                                iconColor: iconColorValue,
                                iconData: iconDataValue,
                              ),
                            );
                          });
                    }),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                const TaskActionButton()
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

And these are the rules I have declared.. let me know if you want screenshots of the firebase console.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /tasks/{taskId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this Permission....

```
 rules_version = '2';
   service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /{document=**} {
   allow read, write: if true;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed my permission to that but it is still giving me permission denied. I just want to make it so that the user can only view tasks that they created and not tasks that other users have created.